# Extract boot.img

Tags: boot, recovery-mode, fastboot, kernel

I have pulled boot.img from my phone's CWM backup. How do I extract it? I tried split_bootimg.pl. But throws an error -

```
Android Magic not found in boot.img. Giving up.
```

Comment: What kind of phone is it from?

Comment: @eldarerathis Sony Xperia P

Comment: Hm, okay. I've seen cases where some devices from smaller manufacturers use non-standard headers on their boot images, but I wouldn't expect that from Sony. I'd try the unpack-bootimg.pl script from [here](https://github.com/beide/Bootimg-scripts), maybe (instructions are covered in detail on [this wiki page](http://android-dls.com/wiki/index.php?title=HOWTO:_Unpack%2C_Edit%2C_and_Re-Pack_Boot_Images)). Perhaps that one will be able to correctly unpack it.

Comment: anirudh@Kat ~/Downloads/mkboot $ ./unpack-bootimg.pl /home/anirudh/Downloads/boot.img-tools/source_img/boot.img 

kernel written to /home/anirudh/Downloads/boot.img-tools/source_img/boot.img-kernel.gz
ramdisk written to /home/anirudh/Downloads/boot.img-tools/source_img/boot.img-ramdisk.cpio.gz
gzip: ..//home/anirudh/Downloads/boot.img-tools/source_img/boot.img-ramdisk.cpio.gz: No such file or directory
cpio: premature end of archive

extracted ramdisk contents to directory /home/anirudh/Downloads/boot.img-tools/source_img/boot.img-ramdisk/

Comment: Related question: [How to unpack and edit `boot.img` for ROM porting?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/69954/107603)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the comment, I spotted the error...

> anirudh@Kat ~/Downloads/mkboot $ ./unpack-bootimg.pl
>   /home/anirudh/Downloads/boot.img-tools/source_img/boot.img kernel
>   written to
>   /home/anirudh/Downloads/boot.img-tools/source_img/boot.img-kernel.gz
>   ramdisk written to
>   /home/anirudh/Downloads/boot.img-tools/source_img/boot.img-ramdisk.cpio.gz
>   gzip:
>   ..//home/anirudh/Downloads/boot.img-tools/source_img/boot.img-ramdisk.cpio.gz:
>   No such file or directory cpio: premature end of archive extracted
>   ramdisk contents to directory
>   /home/anirudh/Downloads/boot.img-tools/source_img/boot.img-ramdisk/

For the `boot.img-ramdisk.cpio.gz` - this needs special handling... try this:

```
gzip -dc boot.img-ramdisk.cpio.gz | cpio -i
```

The way to do it is after unpacking the `boot.img`, create a directory called something like `ramdisk`, go into that directory and use `gzip -dc ../boot.img-ramdisk.cpio.gz | cpio -i`, the reason is, to organize the structure and files with minimum clutter.

`gzip` decompresses the ramdisk archive to `stdout`, pipe it into `cpio` with the `-i` switch to read from `stdin` and it will correctly extract the data.

To do the reverse, say after making a change here and there within the `ramdisk` directory:

```
mkbootfs ramdisk/ | gzip > my_new_ramdisk.gz
```

Comment: it gives me `-dc: No such file or directory`